# Reading images with CV2 is too slow

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have 6000 images with 300*300 pixels, and I have a time problem when I read these images in python.
I need to collect all of the images in a list so that I can use them for my model.
so I write a for loop, read each image, and append it into the X, as a blow code:

```
train_img=sorted(list(paths.list_images("path")))
X=[]
y=[]
for img in train_img:
    X.append(cv2.imread(img))
    y.append(img.split(os.path.sep)[6])
```

but it is very slow! every time I want to work with this data, I have to spend a lot of time collecting all images in one List!

so, Can you give me some advice or recommendations for my problem? and, Is there a package that reads images faster than the Open-CV?

Comment: reading an image file depends on the format of the file. what image file formats do you have? what formats have you tried? are you willing to store the data as uncompressed TIFF or BMP?

Comment: You could pickle your list `X`, so that reading the next time would be a lot faster.

Comment: pickling amounts to resaving the image files as bitmaps/TIFF.

Comment: You don't mention what format the images are currently stored in on disk. Nor if they are 8/16 or 32-bit. Nor if they are colour or greyscale. Nor what OS you use.  Nor how long it currently takes to read them. Nor how many CPU cores you have. Nor if you use turbo-jpeg. Nor what type of disk you have. Nor the filesystem you use....

Comment: Perhaps put on solid state disk as well

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice benchmark of different approaches to reading [here](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/179#issuecomment-618936358). According to it [pyvips](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips) and [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) are good options to consider.

For example,

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
...
im = np.asarray(Image.open(f))
...
```

Also, as [it was suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193338/reading-images-with-cv2-is-too-slow/69193970#comment122300176_69193970), it might be useful to consider other formats for storing images. I guess TIFF or BMP might work out.

Comment: memory pre-allocation is a micro-optimization. the time cost here is due to the file format.

Comment: Agree. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Saving and loading *compressed* image formats will always cost more time than reading uncompressed formats.

You didn't say if you're using JPEG or PNG, which are compressed, or BMP, which is uncompressed. TIFF can be compressed or uncompressed (it can hold JPEG data).

You should convert your data to an uncompressed format. That will take more disk space. Some specific formats of BMP or TIFF can even be "memory-mapped", hence not require much RAM, regardless of size.

I wouldn't recommend "pickling" your data. It's just image data, not arbitrary/general data. It ought to be stored in a typical image file format.

Your choice of libraries:

- OpenCV, which uses various open libraries for its image file I/O
- [Python Imaging Library or Pillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library)
- [`tifffile`](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) which can do the memory mapping trick

Also have a look at [`pyvips`](https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/intro.html#example) which seems to be a wrapper around `libvips`. I haven't used it but another answer pointed it out.

Comment: "Saving and loading compressed image formats will always cost more" - not generally true. There are cases when using compression speeds up things, e.g. when read speed from disk (or remote disk over NFS) is the bottleneck, not the CPU.

Comment: point taken. the throughput alone can be a bottleneck... and ideally it should be, if everything else works optimally (including compression). storing data uncompressed, if that makes it noticeably larger, is a tradeoff that should be considered more carefully than I suggested. -- the type of storage definitely contributes to the time spent. another issue of storage may be the large number of files. seeking on HDDs, processing in the OS/file system driver, or even security measures like a virus scanner, may cause extra cost for every opening of a file, sometimes regardless of its size.

Answer (score 0):

The task is probably [I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound). Try [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), to read the images in parallel/asynchronously. If the files are stored on a slow media such as a network share, use a large number of threads (e.g 32), else less (~CPU count).

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor:
    X = list(executor.map(cv2.imread, train_img))
```

Consider [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) or [dask-image](http://image.dask.org/en/latest/) for more sophisticated use cases.